# JQuery Validation - pattern rule not working and also causes other rules not to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I have the following Regex pattern rule for HTML form inputs that I wish to validate. The pattern rule is meant to follow a pattern for an AWS S3 path (e.g. `s3://bucket/prefix/directory/`). But for some reason, once I added this pattern rule, it, along with all the other rules, stops working.

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#regForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            stack_name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4,
                letterswithbasicpunc: true
            },
            resource_cfn_tmpl_deploy_bucket: {
                required: true
            },
            gpce_ssh_key_pair: {
                required: true
            },
            start_point: {
                required: true
            },
            qc: {
                required: false
            },
            input_uri: {
                required: true,
                pattern: /^s3://([^/]+)/(.*?([^/]+)/?)$/
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since a regex literal is delineated with `/`'s, you have to *escape* any `/` that's part of the pattern.

```
/^s3:\/\/([^\/]+)\/(.*?([^\/]+)\/?)$/
```

(and actually, `/` can appear in a `[]` without causing issues as well, so this also works):

```
/^s3:\/\/([^/]+)\/(.*?([^/]+)\/?)$/
```